# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols from assembly System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm getting the following error when I deploy my application to the server but I don't get this error when I debug it locally:

**System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols from assembly System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0**

Basically, I'm trying to consume an API via:

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
 {                   
               //Do things here
 }
```

It seems like it's blowing up at the using statement. Anyone else come across this? It's weird that I can't reproduce this locally.

Comment: Well, it's true: version 4.0.0 of `System.Net.Primitives` really does not contain that type. Version 4.0.10 (from the latest [4.3.0 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Primitives/4.3.0)) does, though. Verify your deployment. You may have an out of date package, or a mismatch between frameworks (Full vs. Core).

Comment: Thanks, @Jeroen. I'm going to make sure all my packages are synced and up to date. Do you have any ideas why it'd work locally but not on the server though? I've been scratching my head at that one for a while but couldn't come up with a good reason.

Comment: Because, necessarily, locally the correct assembly *is* loaded. I can't peek at your situation remotely, but the fact is that on the server, the correct `System.Net.Primitives` isn't loaded, so there is a difference -- either in the binaries themselves, or the configuration. Maybe the deploy skips copying crucial files. Maybe the configuration is incorrectly adjusted. Maybe you're not deploying to the correct location at all. You can use simple diffing tools like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to compare the server folder with your local folder.